# Cannot get google maps API to load on Wordpress page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, google-maps

I'm trying to display a map I made with the google maps API on my wordpress site. The map seems to load about half of the time. When it doesn't load I get a message suggesting my initMap() function was called before it was declared. There are a few questions asked on a similar topic but I haven't been able to get this to work for me.

```
  <title>Salt City Map</title>

  <div id="map"></div>
  <style type="text/css">
  /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 650px;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

  </style>
  <!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->


  <script>
  window.initMap = function(){
  var syr = {
    lat: 43.0466145,
    lng: -76.1555968
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: syr
  });

  /*
    var testMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: syr,
      map: map,
    }); 
  */

  var visitedPlaces = [
    ['Cathy\'s Cookie Kitchen', 43.0474772, -76.1551454, 'http://www.saltcityblog.com/2017/01/23/theres-something-for-everyone-at-cathys-cookie-kitchen/'],
    ['Liehs & Steigerwald', 43.0488035, -76.1521896, 'http://www.saltcityblog.com/2016/12/19/saturday-lunch-at-liehs-steigerwald/'],
    ['The Evergreen', 43.0507226, -76.153448, 'http://www.saltcityblog.com/2017/01/20/foreva-eva-evergreen-%f0%9f%8c%b2/'],
    ['Soleil Cafe', 43.0306934, -76.0053206, 'http://www.saltcityblog.com/2017/01/13/soleil-cafe-fayetteville/'],
    ['Peppino\'s', 43.0476904, -76.1554043, 'http://www.saltcityblog.com/2017/01/11/peppinos-neapolitan-award-winning-pizza/'],
    ['Original Grain', 43.0486229, -76.154517, 'http://www.saltcityblog.com/2017/01/07/original-grain-healthy-eats-downtown/'],
    ['Cafe Kubal', 43.0469596, -76.1542261, 'http://www.saltcityblog.com/2017/01/02/cafe-kubal-downtown-cafe/'],
    ['Empire Brewery', 43.0481735, -76.156796, 'http://www.saltcityblog.com/2016/12/18/empire-brewing-company-a-syracuse-staple/'],
    ['JJ\'s Miss Syracuse Diner', 43.0502739, -76.151665, 'http://www.saltcityblog.com/2016/12/01/jjs-miss-syracuse-diner/'],
    ['Roji Tea Lounge', 43.0494025, -76.1539753, 'http://www.saltcityblog.com/2016/11/23/late-night-tea-time-roji-tea-lounge/'],
    ['China Cafe', 43.0485356, -76.1568021, 'http://www.saltcityblog.com/2016/11/22/china-cafe-snowy-takeout/'],
    ['Otro Cinco', 43.0492578, -76.1534257, 'http://www.saltcityblog.com/2016/11/21/brunch-at-otro-cinco/'],
    ['Prime Steakhouse', 43.050767, -76.1516991, 'http://www.saltcityblog.com/2016/11/21/first-blog-post/']
  ];

  var marker = [];
  var infowindow = [];
  var contents = [];
  var contentString = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < visitedPlaces.length; i++) {
    var place = visitedPlaces[i]
    var placeLatLng = {
      lat: place[1],
      lng: place[2]
    };

    marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: placeLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: place[0],
      url: place[3]
    });

    marker[i].index = i;

    contentString[i] = '<div id="content">' +
      '<div id="siteNotice">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">' + marker[i].title + '</h1>' +
      '<div id="bodyContent">' +
      '<p>Check out our review <a href="' + marker[i].url + '">' +
      'here!</a></p>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>';

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString[i]
    });
    //console.log(contentString)
    marker[i].setClickable(true);


    marker[i].addListener('click', function() {
      //map.setCenter(marker[this.index].getPosition());
      infowindow.setContent(contentString[this.index]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker[this.index]);
    });
  }

}

  </script>
<script defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBUD-CNsmdQoT7yFXcyrcUqJJToNIoHles&callback=initMap">
  </script>
```

I tried every combination of removing "async" and "defer." I tried putting the callback script after the function declaration. The only pattern I've seen is that it seems to work if I go to my homepage and click the map button, but if I go directly to the map page (SaltCityBlog.com/map) it breaks.

The error I see in the console is:

```
message:"initMap is not a function"
name:"InvalidValueError"
stack:"Error↵    at new Yc (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBUD-CNsmdQoT7yFXcyrcUqJJToNIoHles&callback=initMap:55:363)
```

Thank you.

Comment: check fi you have some error in web console

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring initMap  this way

```
function initMap(){
   var syr = {
      lat: 43.0466145,
      lng: -76.1555968
   };
.....
....



...
}
```

Comment: So this is the way I was originally declaring the function and I switched to the window.initMap method after reading a different stackoverflow post, hoping that it would change the order in which the function is declared as the page is loaded.

Comment: @Jesse   try .. and let me know  .. if work  the is ok .. otherwise . we take another look ..  ... but check for web console error firts .. could be you have ...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon inside the loop for visited places after

```
var place = visitedPlaces[i]
```

it should be

```
var place = visitedPlaces[i];
```

Comment: Thanks. There's something I don't quite understand. How is it that sometimes the map loads 100% fine, no errors. And sometimes I get these two "Caught Syntax error: unexpected end of input" errors *and* the "initMap is not a function" error. 

It really feels like more of a race condition where the page loads differently everytime, rather than a syntax problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can see you've made changes to your function and got rid of the initMap is not a function error but I still get the same error, Unexpected token var, because you still missing the semicolon after var place = visitedPlaces[I] so your script does not execute anything else.